# How to do an http request in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, httprequest

```
POST /1.1/statuses/update.json?include_entities=true HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
User-Agent: OAuth gem v0.4.4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 76
Host: api.twitter.com

status=Hello%20Ladies%20%2b%20Gentlemen%2c%20a%20signed%20OAuth%20request%21
```

How to do an http request, I'm a newbie in Javascript and i need to post a tweet with the api (and i need to implement the sign in button) but I don't understand how to implement this http request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

You can  use jquery plugin to do this so easy:

```
$.post("/1.1/statuses/update.json",
{
    include_entities: "true",

},
function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways.

If you want to do a formal POST, like a form submit, you can construct a form element on your page and submit it. There is a good example of how to do that in this post: [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Otherwise, you can make use of AJAX, which is an asynchronous HTTP request standard, which can be done with vanilla JavaScript or by using a third-party library like JQuery. Mozilla has a great resource for learning how to use AJAX at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this: https://github.com/floscodes/JS/blob/master/Requests.js

You can easily send a http-Request. Just use:

```
HttpRequest("https://example.com", method="post", data="yourkey=yourdata");
```

That's it! It should even work if the site is CSRF-protected.

Or just send a GET-Request by using

```
HttpRequest("https://example.com", method="get");
```